# Recognizing leading contributors and experts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, badges

While surfing SO, I came to know that we have some Microsoft MVP's over here, and they are contributing a lot in making SO more helpful to learners like me.

We have a reputation system running along with badges to acknowledge the efforts, contributions and trust. I have a few suggestions to enhance the existing SO algorithm.

Why don't we create a few badges for:

1. Certified MVP's?
2. Persons holding Ph D's and other master of the art degrees (which can be verified by different sources)?
3. Persons who are known for their astonishing/widely used theories/technologies (e.g Zdenek Kalal for predators)?
4. A person scoring 500+ points in a month with ZERO down-votes (probably a gold badge)?
5. A person whose answers are accepted 100% of the time for a designated time frame (say one month)?

I am hoping, if this suggestion is liked by others, contributors will get more respect, more passion, more acknowledgement of their help.

**EDIT**

I can't understand why almost all the readers over here are getting the words of mine like MVP or points; what I want to transfer is the idea behind the question, to give more respect to the contributor and make more clear that the person is likely to be authentic (based on DEGREE AND FIELD EXPERTISE AND/OR REPUTATION).

All of the above are some suggestions to look into this dimension.

Comment: IMO, this badges will be pointless. Badges are about contribution in SO, not in the whole CS world. You always can write that you're MVP or PhD in your profile -- isn't it enough?

Comment: Okay...Got that, I am not asking for giving some points or reputation to them, I am asking for something that increased the respect of contributors..   And these can be implemented to all fields not specific to MVPs or CS World, as SO is not only covering CS world

Comment: Don't MVP's and Ph.D's, uh, *already have badges?* :)

Comment: Yes, PhD and MVP can be mentioned, but if based on contributions we can create some badges, It will show that the answer provided is like to be authentic as it is being given by some reall professional

Comment: Definitely they have, And these are only Examples, few suggestions

Comment: How does one earn a PhD or MVP based on contributions on SO??? These are totally unrelated to any SO activity, so I can't see **any** reason to have SO badges for them.

Comment: Regarding your edit: What does giving badges to people with Ph.D's actually accomplish?  Does it improve Stack Overflow in some way, or make it run better?  Is the only purpose here to bow down, ["we are not worthy"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FucbvoFFy0) style, to the Ph.D gods?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to "make more clear that The person is likely to be authentic"? This is not a problem we are having.

Comment: I don't agree with the OP's suggestions, for all of the same reasons already articulated; I would also like to point out that my PhD in English doesn't (and *shouldn't*) mean squat to my contributions on SO, UX.SE, PM.SE, & Programmers.SE. The existing SE rep system does.

Comment: One more point. To look at badges list you need to open profile page. Moreover you need to scroll page down and find badge in the list of badges (there could be a lot of them, right?). While tagline is right at your eyes.

Comment: This is almost saying that those who aren't MVPs and Ph.Ds can't contribute as much to Stack Overflow, which is absolutely false and unfair.

Comment: sorry to all if anyone got hurt or had bad feeling because of me, but let me tell you all, that, i was putting forwar suggestions for respecting the contributors, not PHD or MVP only, i was using them as symbol . i cant clear myself again and again..keep on down voting it with out thinking my point and just following the words. thats the real professional approach..thanks to all

Comment: @NewBee Don't do that. We're pretty clever people, we read your post, and we "got it". We disagree. That's what down-votes mean. Your reputation on Stack Overflow is for *Stack Overflow* and **only** Stack Overflow. Your "real world" activities aren't relevant. There are **no** real world credentials (PHD, MVP or any other professional certification) that should influence your rep, even if we could accurately tell who actually had the real-world credentials they claimed to have. The community has weighed and rejected your idea, please don't go off in a childish huff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. No, A Stack Exchange MVP is certified by their Stack Exchange reputation, the number displayed as reputation points and the informal reputation they get from people reading and valuing their contributions.
2. No, a PhD is a pretty big badge already, you don't need a Stack Exchange badge extra.
3. No, badges are for contributions to Stack Exchange sites, if they contribute, they will obtain a lot of badges in no time.
4. No, at least not gold, that's far too easy. Perhaps bronze.
5. <del>A badge for having all your answers in one month (and at least 50, say) accepted, that may be a good idea, not sure yet.</del> No, all in all that would be more likely to induce unwanted behaviour than wanted. It could make people refrain from giving good answers to not jeopardize the badge. The 15 points for the accept must suffice.

Comment: 5) might distort people's answering behaviour, though - you might end up answering a lot less to secure the badge, and stay away entirely from mainstream-type questions... and then 50 would be pretty hard to achieve for anyone who isn't constantly at SO...

Comment: Criteria and Number of questions and ratio can carefully be selected for this

Comment: Hmm, right. Didn't think of that. Maybe > 75% of answers accepted? But I'm not convinced it would be a good idea anyway. (50 was just a number thrown out, could be less.)

Comment: @Daniel either way, it will make people shy away from easy questions. I vote against badge #5. +1 for everything else.

Comment: @DanielFischer - Seeing as badges exist in order to encourage good behaviour (and promote wanted behaviours), I don't really see how #5 (with all the caveats regarding number and %) will promote anything we _want_. Yes, it may promote _some_ people to give answers that are more thoughtful, but at the cost of many less answers by them.

Comment: Yup, convinced.